# OpenGL ES 2: Are vertex and fragment shaders necessary for simple drawing?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I'm currently working on some drawing routines using geometry generated at runtime and only flat colored.  While searching for a minimal GL setup to do my drawing *(I'm matching the screen resolution and on I'm iOS, but the question holds for other ES 2 platforms as well)*, I'm seeing that most examples use vertex and fragment shaders, but not all of them.

If I don't plan to use any textures or lighting *(just direct color copying/blending)* and I don't plan on doing any transformations that can't be done by manipulating the view matrix, do I really need to set up vertex and/or fragment shaders?  If not, is there any advantage to using shaders over a shader-less approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, yes, they are necessary. OpenGL ES 2.0 is not backward compatible with OpenGL ES 1.x and the main differences between the two are custom shaders.

The advantage of using shaders (2.0) or not (1.x) depends on your application's current and long-term functionality, but the fixed-function pipeline of 1.x is quickly becoming a thing of the past. The recently released OpenGL ES 3.0 specification is backward compatible with 2.0, but not 1.x.

OpenGL ES 2.0 uses a programmable pipeline, so you must always declare a vertex and a fragment shader. The simplest ones you can declare for geometry + color are:

```
// Vertex Shader

attribute vec3 position;

void main(void)
{
     gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

and:

```
// Fragment Shader

uniform lowp vec3 color;

void main(void)
{
     gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Source: [Khronos Website & Docs](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/2_X/)

> "The signiﬁcant change in the OpenGL ES 2.0 speciﬁcation is that the
>   OpenGL ﬁxed function transformation and fragment pipeline is not
>   supported."

Comment: The only comment worth adding to this is that GLKit can supply ES 1.x-equivalent shaders for you; see e.g. `GLKBaseEffect`. So ES 2 requires them to be supplied but under iOS there's no need to write them yourself.

Comment: True, good addition @Tommy. However, I would really advise against using GLKBaseEffect because you are not evolving uniformly with OpenGL ES (as seen by the direction of 3.0) and will probably get stuck with irrelevant coding practices. GLKit is great for avoiding tedious boilerplate code in setting up views though.

Comment: Just noticed that this question was re-tagged with "Android", so I guess the GLKit discussion doesn't matter. But I hope it's useful information for any iOS viewers!

Comment: @Tommy: I just came across that as well, and it indeed is useful on iOS.

Comment: @RicardoRendonCepeda: Re-tagged because I didn't scope the problem to iOS-only from the start.  Your answer is a good one, and simple enough to be useful anywhere. ;-)

Comment: so... the gpu is forced to do 400,000 pixel nops for a 800x500 bitmap that only needs to be blit... wouldn't direct bitblt be more efficient in simple 2d graphics? I mean in theory it can recognize that they are nops and be near free but still seems frustratingly expensive

Comment: @Dmitry For my use-cases _(in the 4 years that have passed since I posed this question)_, I've found that doing simple algorithmic graphic generation in shaders is often much faster than blitting from a texture to the screen. I believe this is because to a GPU a handful of math operations and a destination-buffer memory write is relatively inexpensive (especially since the pipeline is optimized for frame buffer writes), but if you blit from a texture, you incur a texture read, which is moderately expensive in comparison. So the “closeness” of data is more important than the number of ops.